# What does google colab's busy status mean?

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

I am training a yolov3 model on custom dataset on colab. After training for around 50 minutes the tab got hanged and now the colab is showing the busy status.

[image]

It is also showing that red alert mark (49m 17s completed at 1:07 PM) at the bottom. What does it mean?

Do I need to interrupt the execution and start the process again?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while performing inference on a pixelcnn, the cell status showed it's running despite a busy kernel (three green dots) & red alert appeared on a status bar.

I kept the code running overnight just to verify and **the cell kept running in the background, code generated the samples.** However, I could not see the cell execution time.

All workspace variables were still present (`%whos`)

Please let me know if this is the case.